# HTML aligning select field

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-table, alignment

I am trying to align two text fields for a t-shirt website, I would like the select fields to be side-by-side and they appear on top of each other. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Color">Color</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size">Size</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="S">S </option>
    <option value="M">M </option>
    <option value="L">L </option>
    <option value="XL">XL </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the use of `<tr>` and `<td>`.  The way I always remember is `<tr>` is `TABLE ROW` ...  Rows are always horizontal and columns hold things, like Greek Towers, up vertically.  Hope this helps.

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Color">Color</td><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Size">Size</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0">
    <option value="White">White</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Grey">Grey</option>
</select> </td>
<td><select name="os1">
    <option value="S">S </option>
    <option value="M">M </option>
    <option value="L">L </option>
    <option value="XL">XL </option>
</select> </td>

</tr>
</table>
```